# How to hook when generating a specific value in frida

Tags: javascript, frida

Good morning

I'm not familiar with frida yet, so I'm going to ask you a question.

When an app communicates, it sends a specific value to the server.

Assume that the com.n.a.w app sends a value of md= 25d7f5e3s5d7f5 to the server.

My goal is to know what information is needed to create how this app generates this 25d7f5e3s5d7f5 value.

For convenience, the package name of the app will be Hook_package = "com.n.a.w".

When I opened the app in jd-gui and looked it, I found a place to create the value "md".

There is a place in the package called "com.n.a.a" that creates the value "md".

Now simple I am trying to code.

I want to know how to get the value "md" with jscode code.

Does anyone know?

Thank you.

```
import sys,frida


Hook_package = "com.n.a.w"

def on_message(message,data):
    print("{} -> {}".format(message,data))

jscode = """

"""

try:
    device = frida.get_usb_device(timeout=10)
    pid = device.spawn([Hook_package])
    print("App is starting.. pid:{}".format(pid))
    process = device.attach(pid)
    device.resume(pid)
    script = process.create_script(jscode)
    script.on('message', on_message)
    print('[*] Running Frida')
    script.load()
    sys.stdin.read()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)enter code here
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The decompiled code is defect and not usable. just look at the `paramMac` value in the method you have highlighted. It is defined as `Mac` but later a `String`is assigned. I assume dex2jar or whatever you used to convert it to jar decompiled it wrong (which is not unusual as converting dex to jar is highly problematic). Hence I strongly recommend to you to use a direct decompiler like Jadx or even better (but to nice to read) apktool and decompile it to Smali code.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for answer. But I have one question. If I want to hook a function or a variable I want, how do I write code?

Comment: You can only hook methods not variables (in a method) or fields. If you search for `frida android` there are dozens of blogs, tutorials, sample scripts how to hook a Java method.